# The response has unexpected status code 0 On server

Tags: php, laravel, server

I run the project on localhost, it is working but when I run or upload files and try to run this on 000webhost server, it is not working and giving me the error

`Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => 0 [message] => The response has unexpected status code (0). Response: ) ) )`

Is there anything that I am missing?

In my usersController.php file code is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

include '../vendor/autoload.php';  

use Mautic\Auth\ApiAuth;
use Mautic\MauticApi;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Contact;

class usersController extends Controller
{

function index(){
    return view('home');
} 

function list(){
    $data = Contact::all();
    return view('list',["data"=>$data]);
}

function add(Request $req){
    //return $req->input();
    
session_start();

// ApiAuth->newAuth() will accept an array of Auth settings
$settings = [
    'userName'   => 'email',             // Create a new user       
    'password'   => 'password',             // Make it a secure password
];

// Initiate the auth object specifying to use BasicAuth
$initAuth = new ApiAuth();
$auth     = $initAuth->newAuth($settings, 'BasicAuth');

// Nothing else to do ... It's ready to use.
// Just pass the auth object to the API context you are creating.
$api        = new MauticApi();
$apiUrl = "https://sampleside.com/api/";
$contactApi = $api->newApi('contacts', $auth, $apiUrl);

    $id   = 18795;
    $data = array(
        'firstname'     => $req->input('firstname'),
        'lastname'     => $req->input('lastname'),
        'email'     => $req->input('email'),   
    );
    
    $createIfNotFound = true;
    
    $response = $contactApi->edit($id, $data, $createIfNotFound);

    print_r($response);
```

I used Mautic API and it is properly working in localhost and in `print_r($response);`
it is printing an array of record that is edited for specified id in the code. But on the server, when I run this code it gives me error :

`Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => 0 [message] => The response has unexpected status code (0). Response: ) ) )`

Comment: Do you have to register to use this API?

Comment: Many APIs will blacklist 000webhost IPs because of ... reasons

Comment: oh! ok got it. can be there any other reason? please tell me. Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't think that I have to register this API. If it is so, then tell me how can I register it?